# How to apply filters parallel in Superpowered SDK

Tags: android, c++, audio, android-ndk

Is it any way to apply filters parallel using Superpowered SDK?

As I understand if I apply filters this way

```
...
filterLowpass->process(inputBufferFloat, inputBufferFloat, numberOfSamples);
filterHighpass->process(inputBufferFloat, inputBufferFloat, numberOfSamples);
filterOther->process(inputBufferFloat, inputBufferFloat, numberOfSamples);
...
```

they are applied in series, right?

Comment: Is `inputBufferFloat` a pointer?

Comment: yes. There was just 
 "  ...     
   filterLowpass->process(inputBufferFloat, inputBufferFloat, numberOfSamples);    
    ... "

in CrossExample, and I've added a couple filters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. In your example they are applied in series. In order to have those filters in parallel, keep the input buffer as inputBufferFloat, but use a distinct output buffer for each filter. Something like:

```
filterLowpass->process(inputBufferFloat, outputFloatFilterLow, numberOfSamples);
filterHighpass->process(inputBufferFloat, outputFloatFilterHigh, numberOfSamples);
filterOther->process(inputBufferFloat, outputFloatFilterOther, numberOfSamples);
```